# Long 'if' conditional in HAML

Tags: haml

So I have a very long conditional in HAML that looks like:

```
- if condition_1 && condition_2 && condition_3
  ...
```

Now, **imagine** that the line is longer than 100 tabs. What's the correct way of breaking that in a multiline?

EDIT:

At some point I thought that something like:

```
- if condition_1 && |
  condition_2 && |
  condition_3
```

Would work. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question has been out for over 4 hours and finally this got me to the answer

https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/845

Long story short... I was missing the pipe at the last line in the conditional